# Why is my server's RAM usage growing all day, then dropping at midnight?

Tags: mysql, memory-usage

My server has started showing new behavior with regard to memory usage.

It used to stay steadily around 40% usage, but now it steadily rises up all day, reaches about 58% at midnight, then instantly drops back down to 40% at exactly midnight local time.

I'm guessing this is something like MySQL dropping some cached data, but I'd like to know for sure. In particular, what's happening at exactly midnight? I don't have any cron jobs scheduled then. How can I check what times mysqld runs cleanup tasks?

This is an Ubuntu 20 server primarily running apache2 and mysql.

mysqltuner.pl output below:

```
 >>  MySQLTuner 2.0.1
         * Jean-Marie Renouard <jmrenouard@gmail.com>
         * Major Hayden <major@mhtx.net>
 >>  Bug reports, feature requests, and downloads at http://mysqltuner.pl/
 >>  Run with '--help' for additional options and output filtering

[--] Skipped version check for MySQLTuner script
[OK] Logged in using credentials from Debian maintenance account.
[OK] Currently running supported MySQL version 8.0.30-0ubuntu0.20.04.2
[OK] Operating on 64-bit architecture
 
-------- Log file Recommendations ------------------------------------------------------------------
[OK] Log file /var/log/mysql/error.log exists
[--] Log file: /var/log/mysql/error.log (0B)
[--] Log file /var/log/mysql/error.log is empty. Assuming log-rotation. Use --server-log={file} for explicit file
 
-------- Storage Engine Statistics -----------------------------------------------------------------
[--] Status: +ARCHIVE +BLACKHOLE +CSV -FEDERATED +InnoDB +MEMORY +MRG_MYISAM +MyISAM +PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA 
[--] Data in InnoDB tables: 1.9G (Tables: 48)
[--] Data in MyISAM tables: 6.6M (Tables: 6)
[OK] Total fragmented tables: 0
 
-------- Analysis Performance Metrics --------------------------------------------------------------
[--] innodb_stats_on_metadata: OFF
[OK] No stat updates during querying INFORMATION_SCHEMA.
 
-------- Views Metrics -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 
-------- Triggers Metrics --------------------------------------------------------------------------
 
-------- Routines Metrics --------------------------------------------------------------------------
 
-------- Security Recommendations ------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] Skipped due to unsupported feature for MySQL 8
 
-------- CVE Security Recommendations --------------------------------------------------------------
[--] Skipped due to --cvefile option undefined
 
-------- Performance Metrics -----------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] Up for: 14d 5h 54m 23s (82M q [66.737 qps], 9M conn, TX: 544G, RX: 17G)
[--] Reads / Writes: 50% / 50%
[--] Binary logging is enabled (GTID MODE: OFF)
[--] Physical Memory     : 7.8G
[--] Max MySQL memory    : 11.8G
[--] Other process memory: 0B
[--] Total buffers: 2.0G global + 65.9M per thread (151 max threads)
[--] P_S Max memory usage: 72B
[--] Galera GCache Max memory usage: 0B
[OK] Maximum reached memory usage: 2.6G (32.96% of installed RAM)
[!!] Maximum possible memory usage: 11.8G (151.35% of installed RAM)
[!!] Overall possible memory usage with other process exceeded memory
[OK] Slow queries: 0% (8K/82M)
[OK] Highest usage of available connections: 5% (8/151)
[OK] Aborted connections: 0.00%  (0/9400218)
[--] Skipped name resolution test due to skip_networking=ON in system variables.
[--] Query cache have been removed in MySQL 8
[!!] Sorts requiring temporary tables: 26% (117K temp sorts / 448K sorts)
[OK] No joins without indexes
[OK] Temporary tables created on disk: 0% (4 on disk / 37K total)
[OK] Thread cache hit rate: 99% (8 created / 9M connections)
[OK] Table cache hit rate: 99% (76M hits / 76M requests)
[OK] table_definition_cache (2000) is greater than number of tables (394)
[OK] Open file limit used: 1% (185/10K)
[OK] Table locks acquired immediately: 99% (110K immediate / 110K locks)
[OK] Binlog cache memory access: 100.00% (35868716 Memory / 35868826 Total)
 
-------- Performance schema ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] Performance_schema is activated.
[--] Memory used by P_S: 72B
[--] Sys schema is installed.
 
-------- ThreadPool Metrics ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] ThreadPool stat is disabled.
 
-------- MyISAM Metrics ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] MyISAM Metrics are disabled on last MySQL versions.
 
-------- InnoDB Metrics ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] InnoDB is enabled.
[--] InnoDB Thread Concurrency: 0
[OK] InnoDB File per table is activated
[OK] InnoDB buffer pool / data size: 2.0G/1.9G
[!!] Ratio InnoDB log file size / InnoDB Buffer pool size (4.6875%): 48.0M * 2/2.0G should be equal to 25%
[!!] InnoDB buffer pool instances: 8
[--] Number of InnoDB Buffer Pool Chunk: 16 for 8 Buffer Pool Instance(s)
[OK] Innodb_buffer_pool_size aligned with Innodb_buffer_pool_chunk_size & Innodb_buffer_pool_instances
[OK] InnoDB Read buffer efficiency: 100.00% (17684791564 hits/ 17684882383 total)
[!!] InnoDB Write Log efficiency: 71.82% (275141861 hits/ 383080665 total)
[OK] InnoDB log waits: 0.00% (0 waits / 107938804 writes)
 
-------- Aria Metrics ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] Aria Storage Engine not available.
 
-------- TokuDB Metrics ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] TokuDB is disabled.
 
-------- XtraDB Metrics ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] XtraDB is disabled.
 
-------- Galera Metrics ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] Galera is disabled.
 
-------- Replication Metrics -----------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] Galera Synchronous replication: NO
[--] No replication slave(s) for this server.
[--] Binlog format: ROW
[--] XA support enabled: ON
[--] Semi synchronous replication Master: Not Activated
[--] Semi synchronous replication Slave: Not Activated
[--] This is a standalone server
 
-------- Recommendations ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
General recommendations:
    Reduce your overall MySQL memory footprint for system stability
    Dedicate this server to your database for highest performance.
    Buffer Key MyISAM set to 0, no MyISAM table detected
    Before changing innodb_log_file_size and/or innodb_log_files_in_group read this: https://bit.ly/2TcGgtU
Variables to adjust:
  *** MySQL's maximum memory usage is dangerously high ***
  *** Add RAM before increasing MySQL buffer variables ***
    sort_buffer_size (> 256K)
    read_rnd_buffer_size (> 256K)
    key_buffer_size=0
    innodb_log_file_size should be (=256M) if possible, so InnoDB total log files size equals 25% of buffer pool size.
    innodb_buffer_pool_instances(=2)
```

Comment: Your server is a pure MySQL server? If not please tell use the other services.

Comment: @Robert also apache2 with PHP-fpm, with about 40 concurrent apache2 processes at any given time. It's hosting a website with a PHP and MySQL backend.

Comment: Apache resets some things after N requests.  (This is probably a way to catch runaway web pages that cannot be stopped any other way.)  MySQL does nothing at midnight without your knowledge, and it has been "up" 14 days.  Do you have any MySQL "EVENTs"?

Comment: @RickJames Nothing in the `information_schema.events` table, if that's what you mean

Comment: Additional information request, please. 
Any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL server? 
Post TEXT data on justpaste.it and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
A) SELECT COUNT(*) FROM information_schema.tables;
AND very helpful OS information, includes - 
htop            1st page, if available, TERMINATE, 
top -b -n 1  for most active apps, 
top -b -n 1 -H  for details on your mysql threads memory and cpu usage, 
ulimit -a       for list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device & core/cpu count, 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: More Additional information request, please. 
Post TEXT data on justpaste.it and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; 
E) STATUS;  not SHOW STATUS, just STATUS;
G) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; 
H) SELECT name, count FROM information_schema.innodb_metrics ORDER BY name; 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: @WilsonHauck justpaste.it crashes when I try to paste in this large file, but you can view it directly at https://squaredle.app/mysql-logs.txt -- thanks for taking a look!

Comment: @WilsonHauck also server logs at https://squaredle.app/server-logs.txt thanks!

Comment: Thank you for your posted data.  Analysis in process.  Will try to have Answer with suggestions in less than 48 hours.

Comment: @mgiuffrida   Still on Digital Ocean hosting?  Any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL server? What time of day is your unattended_upgr scheduled for daily?  Do you have flexibility to Skype Talk with me?  My Skype ID is wlhauck@aol.com  We are in GMT -5 hrs.  Birmingham, AL

Comment: Yes, a single DigitalOcean droplet with "premium" storage (NVMe). Unattended upgrades occur at 02:00, 2 hours after the memory gets freed. Thanks for the offer, but I'd rather keep technical discussions here on ServerFault.

Comment: Ok.  To identify what IS happening around Midnight freeing RAM, please provide from 23:58 A) fresh copy of similar results as mysql-logs.txt, B) fresh copy of similar results as server-logs.txt, C) general log from 23:58 until turning off General Log when RAM has been freed, now that RAM has been freed, D) fresh copy of similar results as mysql-logs.txt, E) fresh copy of similar results as server-logs.txt.  With this information, we should be able to identify HOW your RAM drops consistently around midnight.  Performance suggestions will be provided after this analysis is completed.

Comment: I may have figured it out -- apache2 is using log-rotate to rotate logs right at midnight, which I think causes a config reload. `[Fri Aug 19 00:00:11.474987 2022] [mpm_event:notice] Apache/2.4.41 (Ubuntu) OpenSSL/1.1.1f mod_fcgid/2.3.9 configured -- resuming normal operations` So then the question is, does Apache have a memory leak somehow or is it just reserving memory as it goes?

Comment: Our best hope of helping identify RAM use dropping at midnight could be completed with the data requested about 23 hours ago.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the RAM usage drops exactly at midnight because that's when apache2 is using log-rotate to rotate logs. This causes a config reload:

```
[Fri Aug 19 00:00:11.474987 2022] [mpm_event:notice] Apache/2.4.41 (Ubuntu) OpenSSL/1.1.1f mod_fcgid/2.3.9 configured -- resuming normal operations
```

which for mpm_event means unused processes are recycled. Presumably these processes had memory allocated for past connections that was no longer needed.

Comment: Could you gather the requested data on one Mo-Fr night and the General Log for 23:58 to 00:03 and we will be able to confirm your observation AND get some confirming information that 'Sleeping' processes/threads are not being RELEASED in a timely manner?  Thanks